# Unknown provider on calling a factory on controller "Error: [$injector:unpr]"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have with a problem on call a factory in controller. The factory should do the REST requests on controller calls, but this error is occurring:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SearchServiceProvider <- SearchService <- HomeController
```

I'm trying solve this for some days, but nothing fix this.

**busca.app.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyModule', ['ngMessages'])
    .factory('SearchService', Service);

function Service($http) {
    var service = {};
    
    service.SearchPendingDeliveries = SearchPendingDeliveries;

    return service;

    function SearchPendingDeliveries(docNumberClient, callback) {
        //some code
    }
}
})();
```

**home.controller.js**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyModule', [])
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

function HomeController(SearchService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.searchDeliveriesFromUser = searchDeliveriesFromUser;

    function searchDeliveriesFromUser() {
        SearchService.SearchPendingDeliveries(vm.identifierNumber, function (result) {
            if (result === true) {
                console.log(true);
            } else {
                console.log(false);
            }
        });
    };
};
})();
```

**index.html**

```
 ...
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
 <script src="service/busca.app.js"></script>
 <script src="home/home.controller.js"></script>
 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the same module twice

Try changing

```
angular
    .module('saldanhaTranporte', [])
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

To

```
angular
    .module('saldanhaTranporte')
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

Without the second argument in `module()` it is a getter not a setter and returns reference to an existing module

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I try this, but catch other errors: "Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'saldanhaTranporte' is not available! " and "Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module saldanhaTranporte"

Comment: that *can* be caused by something as simple as a syntax error somewhere if all the orders are correct and files are loading properly. That's not the only reason but is a common one

Comment: ok. So this errors doesn't has relation with the "Unknown Provider"? This errors are caused by something in other code? It's this?